# Can I autobox a single variable in perl?

Tags: perl

I'm using [autobox](https://metacpan.org/pod/autobox) as it allows me to do use [JSON::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::Path) on arbitrary variable like this:

```
use autobox::JSON::Path;
use Mojo::Util qw/dumper/;

my $w = { foo => 'bar', baz => [ 1, 2, 3 ] };

print dumper $w->get('$.baz');
```

where `autobox::JSON::Path` is [here](https://gist.github.com/simonecesano/f6409beb273d98e594cbd685003844b0) (still early code).

This means however that autoboxing affects all hashrefs and arrayrefs.

Is there a way to do it so that it affects only specific variables? or is it actually the same as doing

```
my $w = autobox::JSON::Path::Get->new({ foo => 'bar', baz => [ 1, 2, 3 ] })
```

and that's it?

Comment: *"Is there a way to do it so that it affects only specific variables?"* Why would you like to that? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can use [autobox](https://metacpan.org/pod/autobox) in combination with [JSON::Path](https://metacpan.org/pod/JSON::Path). You can restrict the usage of `autobox` to a specific scope and hence to specific variables like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use JSON::Path;
use Mojo::Util qw/dumper/;

sub HASH::get {
    my ($hash, $arg) = @_;
    my $path = JSON::Path->new($arg);
    return $path->get($hash);
}

my $w = { foo => 'bar', baz => [ 1, 2, 3 ] };

{
    use autobox;
    print dumper $w->get('$.baz');
}
```

**Output**:

```
[
  1,
  2,
  3
]
```